# Sets in R DataFrame

Tags: r

I have a  csv that looks like

```
 Deamon,Host,1:2:4,aaa.03
 Pixe,Paradigm,1:3:5,11.us
```

I need to read this into a dataframe for analysis but the 3rd column in my data is separated by : and need to be read like a set or list 1.e splitted by : so that it returns (1,2,4) . Is it possible to have a columns that has a class list in R . Or How best do you think i can approach this problem.

Comment: Will the third column always have three numbers separated by colons?  Or can it have more than three?

Comment: it can have more than 3 numbers sometimes

Comment: See my answer for differing numbers of `:`'s. You could also look to some other preprocessing tool to handle that for you like `sed` or `awk` if a *nix OS is in your arsenal.

Comment: IMHO you should keep it as '1:3:5' in your data frame and handle the splitting inside any function that uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split a character vector into a list of components:

```
x <- c("1:2:4", "1:3:5")
strsplit(x, split=":")
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "4"

[[2]]
[1] "1" "3" "5"
```

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, the answer will vary depending on if the number of separators in the columns are consistent or not. The answer is more straight forward if that number is consistent. Here's one answer to do that building off of Andrie's `strsplit` answer:

```
dat <- read.csv("yourData.csv", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#If always going to be a consistent number of separators
dat <- cbind(dat, do.call("rbind", strsplit(dat[, 3], ":")))

       V1       V2      V3     V4 1  2  3
1  Deamon     Host 1:02:04 aaa.03 1 02 04
2    Pixe Paradigm 1:03:05  11.us 1 03 05
```

Note that the above is essentially how `colsplit.character` from package `reshape` is implemented and may be a better option for you as it forces you to give proper names.

If the number of separators is different, then using `rbind.fill` is an option from package `plyr`. `rbind.fill` expects data.frames which was a bit annoying, and I couldn't figure out how to get a one row data.frame without first converting to a matrix, so I imagine this can be made more efficient, but here's the basic idea:

```
library(plyr)
x <- c("1:2:4", "1:3:5:6:7")
rbind.fill(
  lapply(
    lapply(strsplit(x, ":"), matrix, nrow = 1)
  , as.data.frame)
)

  V1 V2 V3   V4   V5
1  1  2  4 <NA> <NA>
2  1  3  5    6    7
```

Which can then be `cbind`ed as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using gsub to replace that character:

```
R> str <- "1:2:4"
R> str
[1] "1:2:4"
R> gsub(":", ",", str)
[1] "1,2,4"
```

Make sure the column is a string not a factor beforehand.