# Split column at delimiter in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to split one column into two within at data frame based on a delimiter. For example,

```
a|b
b|c
```

to become

```
a    b
b    c
```

within a data frame.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033187/sets-in-r-dataframe/7033933#7033933

Answer (score 128, accepted):

@Taesung Shin is right, but then just some more magic to make it into a `data.frame`.
I added a "x|y" line to avoid ambiguities:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b','b|c','x|y'))
foo <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$FOO),'|',fixed=TRUE)))
```

Or, if you want to replace the columns in the existing data.frame:

```
within(df, FOO<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(FOO), '|', fixed=TRUE))))
```

Which produces:

```
  ID FOO.X1 FOO.X2
1 11      a      b
2 12      b      c
3 13      x      y
```

Comment: What would you do if it's one column within a pre-existing large dataframe with 100s of columns?

Comment: good question.  I would do the split, make it into a data frame, rename it appropriately (the `rename` function from the `reshape` package is handy for doing this on the fly) and then `rbind` it with the existing data frame -- extra effort to get it inserted in place of the previous single column rather than as the first or last columns ...

Comment: I my updated version handles several 100s of other columns too.

Comment: +1 This is the most generic solution. It even can handle the situations where there are different numbers of values separated by '|'. Of course, one has to deal with the result of rbind which may recycle for those rows with fewer elements. But the other solution would fail for such case.

Comment: Be careful, `length(strsplit('a|', '|', fixed=TRUE))` is `1` -- as [the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) say: "...but if there is a match at the end of the string, the output is the same as with the match removed." As @YuShen says, this solution will "recycle". For me, I just wanted empty spaces, not recycling.

Comment: This does the job, thanks! (Just bear in mind that it's quite slow, so I'm trying other options too)

Comment: If the number of items between rows is different (e.g., a|b, b|c, x|y|z), is there a way to fill what should be empty with NA? With this code, the separated values are repeated rather than empty

Answer (score 104):

The `tidyr` package has a helper function for this, `separate_wider_delim()` (which superseded `separate()` in `tidyr` version 1.3.0 (2023-01-24):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b', 'b|c', 'x|y'))
library(tidyr)
separate_wider_delim(df, cols = FOO, delim = "|", names = c("left", "right"))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#      ID left  right
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1    11 a     b    
# 2    12 b     c    
# 3    13 x     y
```

For `tidyr` versions < 1.3.0:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b', 'b|c', 'x|y'))
separate(data = df, col = FOO, into = c("left", "right"), sep = "\\|")

#   ID left right
# 1 11    a     b
# 2 12    b     c
# 3 13    x     y
```

though in this case the defaults are smart enough to work (it looks for non-alphanumeric characters to split on).

```
separate(data = df, col = FOO, into = c("left", "right"))
```

Comment: This looks cool at first sight, but how do I put the result back together in a data frame?

Comment: @FlorinAndrei `separate` returns a data frame. No extra work is needed.

Answer (score 65):

Hadley has a very elegant solution to do this inside data frames in his `reshape` package, using the function `colsplit`.

```
require(reshape)
> df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b','b|c','x|y'))
> df
  ID FOO
1 11 a|b
2 12 b|c
3 13 x|y
> df = transform(df, FOO = colsplit(FOO, split = "\\|", names = c('a', 'b')))
> df
  ID FOO.a FOO.b
1 11     a     b
2 12     b     c
3 13     x     y
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this without the resultant column names as "FOO.a" and  "FOO.b" but just as "a" and "b" (easy enough to change, but just wondering...)?

Comment: You could do the following `with(df, cbind(ID, colsplit(df$FOO, pattern = "\\|", names = c('a', 'b'))))`. Note that the parameter `split` has been renamed to `pattern` in `reshape2` which is a later version of the `reshape` package.

Comment: My edit is prevented at the moment... I would just update your answer to print df after each assignment...

    require(reshape)
    > df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b','b|c','x|y'))
    > df
      ID FOO
    1 11 a|b
    2 12 b|c
    3 13 x|y
    > df = transform(df, FOO = colsplit(FOO, split = "\\|", names = c('a', 'b')))
    > df
      ID FOO.a FOO.b
    1 11     a     b
    2 12     b     c
    3 13     x     y

Comment: Also, is there a way to do it if you don't know the number of columns which would result?

Comment: Small problem with this solution.  It splits the columns into a 'nested' dataframe, so that if you need to use the data for a plot using `ggplot2`, the column names are not recognized.  I've found the `separate` function in `tidyr` more useful for this purpose.  See answer by `@Gregor`

Answer (score 50):

Just came across this question as it was linked in [a recent question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390090/how-to-split-column-by-into-multiple-columns).

Shameless plug of an answer: Use `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b','b|c','x|y'))
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, "FOO", "|")
#   ID FOO_1 FOO_2
# 1 11     a     b
# 2 12     b     c
# 3 13     x     y
```

This particular function also handles splitting multiple columns, even if each column has a different delimiter:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, 
                 FOO=c('a|b','b|c','x|y'), 
                 BAR = c("A*B", "B*C", "C*D"))
cSplit(df, c("FOO", "BAR"), c("|", "*"))
#   ID FOO_1 FOO_2 BAR_1 BAR_2
# 1 11     a     b     A     B
# 2 12     b     c     B     C
# 3 13     x     y     C     D
```

---

<s>Essentially, it's a fancy convenience wrapper for using `read.table(text = some_character_vector, sep = some_sep)` and binding that output to the original `data.frame`. In other words, another</s> A base R approach could be:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, FOO=c('a|b','b|c','x|y'))
cbind(df, read.table(text = as.character(df$FOO), sep = "|"))
  ID FOO V1 V2
1 11 a|b  a  b
2 12 b|c  b  c
3 13 x|y  x  y
```

Comment: I particularly like that you don't have to define the column names the data is going 'into'

Comment: Agree with tospig. I also love that native method `read.table(c('a|b','c|d'), '|')` can do the trick if we're creating a new data.frame, even though SO talked about "within a [existing] data frame."

Comment: Downside of read.table, sep can only be one byte, and a hash separator is interpreted as a comment?  `read.table(text=c('a#b'), sep='#')` produces only one column -- I expected two columns.

Comment: @TheRedPea, on a phone right now, but can't you get the result you want by also specifying the comment character in `read.table` as `""`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto you're absolutely correct; this produces 2 columns: `read.table(text=c('a#b'), sep='#', comment.char = '')` and as for the single-character delimiter, if I pass the c('a~~b') into gsub I can get the single-byte delimiter I need: `gsub('~~','~', c('a~~b'))`

Answer (score 12):

```
strsplit(c('a|b','b|c'),'|',fixed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Combining @Ramnath and @Tommy's answers allowed me to find an approach that works in base R for one or more columns.

Basic usage:

```
> df = data.frame(
+   id=1:3, foo=c('a|b','b|c','c|d'), 
+   bar=c('p|q', 'r|s', 's|t'), stringsAsFactors=F)
> transform(df, test=do.call(rbind, strsplit(foo, '|', fixed=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors=F)
  id foo bar test.1 test.2
1  1 a|b p|q      a      b
2  2 b|c r|s      b      c
3  3 c|d s|t      c      d
```

Multiple columns:

```
> transform(df, lapply(list(foo,bar),
+ function(x)do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, '|', fixed=TRUE))), stringsAsFactors=F)
  id foo bar X1 X2 X1.1 X2.1
1  1 a|b p|q  a  b    p    q
2  2 b|c r|s  b  c    r    s
3  3 c|d s|t  c  d    s    t
```

Better naming of multiple split columns:

```
> transform(df, lapply({l<-list(foo,bar);names(l)=c('foo','bar');l}, 
+                          function(x)do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, '|', fixed=TRUE))), stringsAsFactors=F)
  id foo bar foo.1 foo.2 bar.1 bar.2
1  1 a|b p|q     a     b     p     q
2  2 b|c r|s     b     c     r     s
3  3 c|d s|t     c     d     s     t
```