# Re-model the shape of my data.frame/excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, dataframe, structure, gsub, stringr

this is my first question on this forum.

I would like to re-model the structure of my dataset.
I would like to split the column "Teams" into two columns. One with the hometeam and another with the awayteam.
I also would like to split the result into two columns. Homegoals and Awaygoals. The new columns should not have a zero infront of the "real" goals scored.

**BEFORE**

```
Date        Time    Teams               Results Homewin Draw    Awaywin
18 May      19:45   AC Milan - Sassuolo 02:01   1.26    6.22    10.47
18 May      19:45   Chievo - Inter      02:01   3.73    3.42    2.05
18 May      19:45   Fiorentina - Torino 02:02   2.84    3.58    2.39
```

**AFTER**

```
Date Time Hometeam Awayteam Homegoals Awaygoals Homewin Draw    Awaywin
18 May  19:45   AC Milan    Sassuolo    2   1   1.26    6.22    10.47
18 May  19:45   Chievo      Inter       2   1   3.73    3.42    2.05
18 May  19:45   Fiorentina  Torino      2   2   2.84    3.58    2.39
```

Can R fix this problem for me? Which packages do i need?
I want to be able to do this for many excel spreadsheets with different leagues and divisions but all with the same structure.

Can someone help me and my data.frame?

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr` solution:

```
separate(your.data.frame, Teams, c('Home', 'Away'), sep = " - ")
```

Base R solution (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame)):

```
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(your.df$teams), " - ")))
names(df) <- c("Home", "Away")
```

Comment: Base R solution.
This one works great too. I prefer this one because of its simplicity without any packages.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses `cSplit` from the `splitstackshape` package, which uses and returns a `data.table`.  Presuming your original data frame is named `df`,

```
library(splitstackshape)

setnames(
    cSplit(df, 3:4, c(" - ", ":"))[, c(1:2, 6:9, 3:5), with = FALSE], 
    3:6, 
    paste0(c("Home", "Away"), rep(c("Team", "Goals"), each = 2))
)[]
#      Date  Time   HomeTeam AwayTeam HomeGoals AwayGoals Homewin Draw Awaywin
# 1: 18 May 19:45   AC Milan Sassuolo         2         1    1.26 6.22   10.47
# 2: 18 May 19:45     Chievo    Inter         2         1    3.73 3.42    2.05
# 3: 18 May 19:45 Fiorentina   Torino         2         2    2.84 3.58    2.39
```

Comment: This looks great!
I will try it again tomorrow or on monday. But it looks promising :D