# Split Author name from publication year in a data frame

Tags: r

I was wondering how I could be able to split the Author name from the study year and put them in separate columns. The data frame that I have is as below:

```
df <- 
Study                N
John et al., 2003    10
Nich et al., 1988    15
```

Result should be:

```
df <-
Study         Year    N
John et al.,  2003    10
Nich et al.,  1988    15
```

I am using R.

Comment: Do any of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame) help?

Comment: @alexforrence The answers there deal with specific case. I wasn't able to apply them to my dataframe. My data frame has other columns that I don't want to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to select both parts

```
df$Year <- gsub("^.*, ", "", df$Study) #remove everything before ", "
df$Study <- gsub(",.*$", "", df$Study) #remove everything after ","
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with extract from tidyr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(Study, c("Author", "Year"), "(.*), ([0-9]{4})")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`, split the 'Study' using `tstrsplit`, and change the column names with `setnames`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setnames(setDT(df)[, c(tstrsplit(Study, '(?<=,) ', perl=TRUE), 
                list(N=N))], 1:2, c('Year', 'Study'))[]
#           Year Study  N
#1: John et al.,  2003 10
#2: Nich et al.,  1988 15
```