# Divide rows in a given column by a name-speficied row

Tags: r, dataframe, row, names, divide

Having a dataframe in R, I'd like to divide all rows in a given column by a name-speficied row (here 'ABC') from the same column, and apply these to all the columns using this specific row as the normalizer.

Input:

```
A   1   1
B   1   2
C   4   4
ABC 2   2
E   2   3
```

Output:

```
A   0.5 0.5
B   0.5 1
C   2   2
ABC 1   1
E   1   1.5
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please produce a reproducible example with sample code and the corresponding data extract? You may also consider being more specific in your request, do you want to [split the column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7069076/1655567) or split *(which in effect would correspond to subsetting )* the rows in the data frame according to column values?

Comment: Sorry, uploaded accidentally too early. I only want to divide, always by ABC for each column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is

```
df1[-1] <- df1[-1]/df1[df1$v1=='ABC', -1][col(df1[-1])]
```