# convert data frame that is separated by one or more spaces

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has the column separated by one or more spaces. I would like to convert the data frame into a tab separated data frame that splits the strings where the spaces are.

This data frame was converted from a list, thats why it has the dots.

```
[1973,] "hsa_let_7a_5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGC_0_I_C_0_tt -0.2148    0.8067   0.1859 -1.156    0.248"          
[1974,] "hsa_let_7a_5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGC_0_I_C_0_tt    0.8067       1.24    0.5604     1.161"            
[1975,] "hsa_let_7c_5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTC_0_I_C_0_t 0.1345    1.1439   0.1914 0.703    0.482"            
[1976,] "hsa_let_7c_5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATGGTC_0_I_C_0_t     1.144     0.8742    0.7861     1.665"            
[1977,] "hsa_miR_25_3p_CATTGCACTTGTCTCGGTCT_0_0_0_ga 0.05551   1.05708  0.16326 0.34    0.734"               
[1978,] "hsa_miR_25_3p_CATTGCACTTGTCTCGGTCT_0_0_0_ga     1.057      0.946    0.7676     1.456"
```

Comment: this answer may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame

Comment: Please make this reproducible.  See [mcve]