# Split column at multiple-character delimiter in data frame

Tags: r

My question is very similar to the question below, with the added problem that I need to split by a double-space.

[Split column at delimiter in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame)

I would like to split this vector into columns.

```
text <- "first       second and second     third and third and third               fourth"
```

The result should be four columns reading "first", "second and second", "third and third and third", "fourth"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `\\s{2,}` to match the pattern of space that are 2 or more in `strsplit`

```
v1 <- strsplit(text, "\\s{2,}")[[1]]
v1
#[1] "first"                     "second and second"    
#[3] "third and third and third" "fourth"
```

This can be converted to `data.frame` using `as.data.frame.list`

```
setNames(as.data.frame.list(v1), paste0("col", 1:4))
```