# Split a column of a data frame to multiple columns without duplicate

Tags: r, split

I would like to split one column into two within at data frame based on a delimiter. For example,

```
METHAMPHETAMINE | MORPHINE
THC
```

to became

```
METHAMPHETAMINE  MORPHINE
THC
```

within a data frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `gsub()` to identify and extract either side of the vertical pipe in your single column:

```
df <- data.frame(col=c('METHAMPHETAMINE | MORPHINE', 'THC'))
df$col1 <- gsub("(.*)\\s*\\|.*", "\\1", df$col)
df$col2 <- ifelse(grepl(".*\\|\\s*(.*)", df$col),
                  gsub(".*\\|\\s*(.*)", "\\1", df$col), 
                  "")

df
                         col             col1      col2
1 METHAMPHETAMINE | MORPHINE  METHAMPHETAMINE  MORPHINE
2                        THC              THC
```

## Demo

Your question is something of a curve ball, because from your sample data we can see that not every row in the data frame may have a pipe with a second column.  It is a feature of `gsub()` to return the input string when no match is found, but in our case, we just want empty string if no pipe is present.  One option here is to use `grepl()` to first check if the pattern matches, and if not, then return empty string.

Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns), though a new application of the answers given there would be required to answer your question.

Comment: Not a lot to change from the possible duplicate question - `str_split_fixed(df$col, fixed(" | "), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
> a1=read.csv("test.csv",header=F)
> a1
                          V1
1 METHAMPHETAMINE | MORPHINE
2                        THC


> within(a1, FOO<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(V1), '|', fixed=TRUE))))
                          V1           FOO.X1    FOO.X2
1 METHAMPHETAMINE | MORPHINE METHAMPHETAMINE   MORPHINE
2                        THC              THC       THC
```

from

[Split column at delimiter in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame)