# Separate numbers in a fraction in R

Tags: r, fractions

I wan to separate the numbers in fraction in to two different columns.

Before splitting

```
 B.P 
127/80
130/98
```

After splitting( This is how i want):

```
B.P       upper      lower
127/80     127        80
130/98     130        98
```

Comment: A frequent duplicate around here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350440/split-a-column-of-a-data-frame-to-multiple-columns for instance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame

Comment: if using base R:  `strcapture("(.*)\\/(.*)",B.P,data.frame(upper=numeric(),lower=numeric()))`

Comment: `do.call(rbind,strsplit(B.P,"\\/"))`

Comment: Don't use `strcapture`. Use `strsplit`

Comment: @DanHall  whats wrong with `strcapture`?

Comment: It's new in 3.4.1. Users on OSX10.9 and earlier can't access versions of R that use it.