# Split concatenated column to corresponding column positions

Tags: r, string, dataframe, split

I have a data frame where a column may contain concatenated characters separated by `|`:

```
df <- data.frame(FOO = c('A|B|C', 'A|B', 'B|C', 'A', 'C'))

# df
#     FOO
# 1 A|B|C
# 2   A|B
# 3   B|C
# 4     A
# 5     C
```

I want to split the string and put the individual values into different columns:

```
df
#  X1 X2 X3
# 1 A  B  C
# 2 A  B
# 3    B  C
# 4 A
# 5       C
```

So far I tried with this example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame][1] but it is not splitting the columns without repeating values, what I get there is:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(df$FOO),'|',fixed=TRUE)))

> df
  X1 X2 X3
1  A  B  C
2  A  B  A
3  B  C  B
4  A  A  A
5  C  C  C
```

And I also get this warning:

> Warning message: In rbind(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B"), c("B", "C"),
> "A", "C") :   number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector
> length (arg 2)

What can I do in those cases? Preferably with `base` R.
[1]: [Split column at delimiter in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame)

Comment: Would the dataframe have values A, B, C... always ? I mean how do we decide which column a particular value should go?

Comment: No, values might change but names remain the same. For example: `row1 = A|B|C` and `row22 = B|D|F`.

Comment: So if you have only these two rows how many columns would you have? 6 (A, B, C, D, E, F) or 5 (A, B, C, D, F) ?

Comment: At the begining (in `df`) I have only one column with a changing number of rows. What it is inside the rows (`A|B|C`) always changes. Sometimes the max length can be 7 (`A|B|C|D|E|F|G`), others 1 (`A`), others 2 (`A|C`), and so on.

Comment: One last thing I want to tell you: When you look at `df` you see your column is of type `factor`. That's  often a very unwanted thing. So you could add `,stringsAsFactors=F` into the data.frame definition.

Comment: Yes, just added `as.data.frame()` and `stringsAsFactors = F` and it still works great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: are your values always a single letter? such as `A|C` and not `cat|dog3`?

Comment: The accepted answer works for single letters and words. So that is not really important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply do:

```
splt <- strsplit(as.character(df$FOO),"\\|")
all_val <- sort(unique(unlist(splt)))
t(sapply(splt,function(x){all_val[!(all_val %in% x)]<-NA;all_val}))


#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
#[2,] "A"  "B"  NA  
#[3,] NA   "B"  "C" 
#[4,] "A"  NA   NA  
#[5,] NA   NA   "C"
```

**data:**

```
df <- data.frame(FOO = c('A|B|C', 'A|B', 'B|C', 'A', 'C'))
```

**Please note:**

My version is `base::` (no libraries needed) and general:

It would also work with:

```
df <- data.frame(FOO = c('A|B|C', 'A|B', 'B|C', 'A', 'C', 'B|D|F'))
```

Comment: Short, general and using `base::`... It works great! Thank you.

Comment: It was a well-posed question and an interesting problem!

Comment: Please note the result is a `matrix` if that is problematic for you, just wrap `as.data.frame()` around it.

Answer (score 7):

Overlooked that OP asked for a `base R` solution. Please try @AndreElrico's, @r.user.05apr's or @milan's solutions.

---

This can be done with `cSplit_e` from the `splitstackshape` package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(
  data = df,
  split.col = "FOO",
  sep = "|",
  mode = "value",
  type = "character",
  fill = " ",
  drop = TRUE
)
#  FOO_A FOO_B FOO_C
#1     A     B     C
#2     A     B      
#3           B     C
#4     A            
#5                 C
```

---

Does also work in case of the following df (see OP's comment above).

```
(df1 <- data.frame(FOO = c('A|B|C', 'A|B', 'B|C', 'A', 'C', 'B|D|F')))
#    FOO
#1 A|B|C
#2   A|B
#3   B|C
#4     A
#5     C
#6 B|D|F

cSplit_e(df1, "FOO", "|", "value",  "character", TRUE, fill = " ")
#  FOO_A FOO_B FOO_C FOO_D FOO_F
#1     A     B     C            
#2     A     B                  
#3           B     C            
#4     A                        
#5                 C            
#6           B           D     F
```

Answer (score 4):

In base R:

```
df <- data.frame(FOO = c('A|B|C', 'A|B', 'B|C', 'A', 'C'))

dummy <- strsplit(as.character(df$FOO), "[|]")
want <- data.frame(values = unlist(dummy),
                   ids = rep(1:length(dummy), unlist(lapply(dummy, length))), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(reshape2)
want <- dcast(want, ids ~ values, value.var = "values", fill = " ")[, -1] # first col removed
names(want) <- paste0("X", seq_along(unique(unlist(dummy)))) 
want
# X1 X2 X3
#1  A  B  C
#2  A  B   
#3     B  C
#4  A      
#5        C
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but why does this retrieves the values as rows? Is there a way to keep the columns of the `df`?

Comment: Sorry! I just saw you used a library to "reshape" the columns. I thought they were different examples :-P

Answer (score 2):

Use `unique` and `strsplit` to find all unique values (`A`, `B` and `C` in this case). Use `grep` to search for the unique values, and return the values when there's a match or `character(0)` otherwise. `cbind` the resulting characters. Use `apply` and `ifelse` to replace `character(0)` with `NA`.

```
vals <- unique(unlist(sapply(a1, function(x) strsplit(x, '|', fixed = T))))

out <- NULL
for(i in vals){
  out <- cbind(out, as.character((lapply(df$FOO, function(x) grep(x, i, value=T)))))
}

apply(out, 2, function(x) ifelse(x=="character(0)", NA, x))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "A"  "B"  NA  
[3,] NA   "B"  "C" 
[4,] "A"  NA   NA  
[5,] NA   NA   "C"
```

Comment: Let's say I have 80 letters (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`...) then do I have to use `grep` for each one of the cases?

Comment: Changed it now so that you can easily apply it to many values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` as well

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  separate_rows(FOO, sep="[|]") %>% 
  mutate(L=factor(FOO, labels = paste0("X",1:length(unique(FOO))))) %>% 
  spread(L, FOO) %>% 
  select(-1)
    X1   X2   X3
1    A    B    C
2    A    B <NA>
3 <NA>    B    C
4    A <NA> <NA>
5 <NA> <NA>    C
```

It is also generally working e.g. `df <- data.frame(FOO = c('A|B|C', 'A|B', 'B|C', 'A', 'C', 'B|D|F'))`. In addition you can set the levels e.g. B>C>A by yourself using `levels = c("B", "C", "A")` in the factor function in the mutate step.