# Is there a way to split a character vector into two columns?

Tags: r

I have a column vector composed of characters like these : "2L.70660", "2L.80704" and "X.92727". I want to split this single vector at the "." into two new columns "2L", "2L" and "70660", "80704", and "92727". I'm not really sure the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame) or `strsplit` or `tidyr::separate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `v` in the Note at the end use `read.table`.  No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = v, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE)
```

giving this data.frame:

```
  V1    V2
1 2L 70660
2 2L 80704
3  X 92727
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
v <- c("2L.70660", "2L.80704", "X.92727")
```