# How can I change the cell format from ":" to lat and long (degree, minute, second) type

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, column-types

The data has 34773 rows and 28 column. One of these columns contains the latitude and the other longitude information for each row.
But these coordinates are supposed to be separated in degrees minutes seconds (° ' ''), but instead they are separated by colons. How can I change this?

[image: Relevant columns]

Comment: Look at `help(gsub)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi [enesson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11125111/enesson),

Be careful because you haven't read the names of the variables as its first line, that is, the `header` parameter. So, you will have to adapt the second line of this code to your data.

As you can see here, I used the `separate` function according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame). It may be useful for you!

```
library(tidyr)
df <- read.csv("your_data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
df1 <- separate(data = df, col = KUZEY, into = c("lat_degrees", "lat_minutes", "lat_seconds"), sep = ":")
df2 <- separate(data = df1, col = DOGU, into = c("lon_degrees", "lon_minutes", "lon_seconds"), sep = ":")
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi Esther, thank you for your support. I solved it with this code.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to hear it!