# Having a trouble to separate the names in a data frame

Tags: r, plyr

I am having trouble separating the names in a data frame. Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the data frame code.

```
Classe1 <- c("class1", "class2", "class3","class1", "class2", "class3","class1", "class2", "class3")
Marks.class <- c(12,14,54,67,87,8,17,11,20)
Students <- c("Thom Eric", "Sandra Leaf", "Fanta derrick", "Nike Gael", "Dan JD","Thom Eric","Sandra Leaf", "Sandra Leaf","Sandra Leaf")
Class.perf <- data.frame(Classe1,Marks.class,Students)
```

And I Want to separate the names in the students's column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y127Y.png)

Comment: This should be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame

Comment: You're having trouble, what did you do that is not working?

Comment: Thank you so much, All. I used this code and the problem has been solved. 
separate(data = Class.perf, col = Students, into = c("First.name", "Second.name"))

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you so much, All. I used this code and the problem has been solved. `separate(data = Class.perf, col = Students, into = c("First.name", "Second.name"))`

-OP

You could also use `separate_wider_*()`. [Check the documentation.](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html)